# will java outer class compilation effects inner class

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I need to give a patch to websphere. where I have a main java class which has three inner classes. I have few code changes to main class but no changes to any inner classes. Now my question is should I need to give all innerclasses along with main class file as a part of patch or main class alone sufficient?

Comment: this question seems nonsense. Inner classes are in the same file with outer class. Inner classes are parts of main class, just like methods, variables are. So you cannot give main class _alone_ technically. You give the changed file, that's all.

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez: Yes you can. Inner classes don't really "exist" in bytecode (i.e. `.class` files)

Comment: @LukasEder They do - these are the `.class` files with dollar signs in their names.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes, I know. But formally, they're different classes altogether. "Inner classes" are a Java-the-language feature, IMO

Comment: @LukasEder so tell me how can you give main class without its inner classes? How will websphere get the association of the former inner classes with your _new_ main class?

Comment: Could you not just diff the .class files? I don't expect they would change, but that would certainly tell you.

Comment: @LukasEder Ah, you're right, I see exactly what you mean, and understand why you put double-quotes around "exist" :)

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez: Inner classes are translated by the compiler to regular top-level classes through a naming convention using a `$` sign to indicate the "nesting level". By "coincidence" two compilation runs can re-generate the same class names (e.g. `Outer$1.class`). But with anonymous classes, there's no guarantee... If you're sure that the same class-names are re-generated for inner classes, then it's probably sufficient to patch only the outer class

Answer (score 3):

This is not an authoritative answer, but every time I did such patching, I copied all the classes (outer *and* inner classes), i.e.

```
Outer.class
Outer$1.class     // These indexes might change ...
Outer$2.class     // ... between compilation runs
Outer$Inner.class // This name should never change
```

When I didn't do this, there were usually some late classloading side-effects. In my opinion, this most often happened because of *anonymous* inner classes, which do not always re-generate the same "anonymous class index" (as in `$1`, `$2`, etc), depending on their order in the `.java` file.

So, to be sure, as this sort of patching is quite a hooligan technique anyway, I always copied all of the classes.

Comment: +1 Your point about anonymous classes is an especially valuable one.

Comment: If we dont have "anonymous inner classes" then Adam may be correct?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: I would expect so, yes. In that case, you could patch only the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

Inner class is just like normal class with implicit reference to outer class so I would say it is safe to give only outer class **if** you really didn't change the inner ones.

Comment: If we dont have "anonymous inner classes" then your point is valid as it generates the class files always with same names.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna that's correct. Changing the creation order of anonymous inner classes can produce different class names in FS as Lukas mentioned